# Transforming rectangular matrices to square matrices in a loop

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list variable x9 that stores three elements

```
  x9[[1]]

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

  x9[[2]]

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

  x9[[3]]

  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

My goal is to take each of these x9[[1]] , x9[[2]] , x9[[3]] ,...and convert them to a square matrix . The unmatched/unrelated rows and columns should be padded with zeros. For example the first element x9[[1]] should be transformed to a square matrix as below

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0**
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
66 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

only row 2 contains 1 and 0 rest are all 0's

Similarly x9[[3]] should be transformed as shown below.

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 63 64 65 66 67
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0**
 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
10 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
11 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
13 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
14 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
15 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
17 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
18 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
19 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
63 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
66 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
67 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

This should happen in a loop, any advise on how to do this would be helpful.

```
structure(list(`0000000000000000000000000`=structure(list(`0`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`1`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`2`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`3`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`4`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`5`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`6`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`7`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`8`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`9`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`10`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`11`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`12`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`13`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`14`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`15`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`16`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`17`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`18`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`19`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`63`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`64`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`65`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`66`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),`67`=c(0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names=c("6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13",
"14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66","67"
),class="data.frame"),`0000000000000000000011111`=structure(list(
`0`=0,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=0,`5`=0,`6`=0,
`7`=0,`8`=0,`9`=0,`10`=0,`11`=0,`12`=0,
`13`=0,`14`=0,`15`=0,`16`=0,`17`=0,`18`=0,
`19`=0,`63`=1,`64`=1,`65`=1,`66`=1,`67`=1),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="3",class="data.frame"),`0000000100000000111100000`=structure(list(
`0`=0,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=0,`5`=0,`6`=0,
`7`=1,`8`=0,`9`=0,`10`=0,`11`=0,`12`=0,
`13`=0,`14`=0,`15`=0,`16`=1,`17`=1,`18`=1,
`19`=1,`63`=0,`64`=0,`65`=0,`66`=0,`67`=0),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="4",class="data.frame"),`0000001111100000000000000`=structure(list(
`0`=0,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=0,`5`=0,`6`=1,
`7`=1,`8`=1,`9`=1,`10`=1,`11`=0,`12`=0,
`13`=0,`14`=0,`15`=0,`16`=0,`17`=0,`18`=0,
`19`=0,`63`=0,`64`=0,`65`=0,`66`=0,`67`=0),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="5",class="data.frame"),`0111110000000000000000000`=structure(list(
`0`=0,`1`=1,`2`=1,`3`=1,`4`=1,`5`=1,`6`=0,
`7`=0,`8`=0,`9`=0,`10`=0,`11`=0,`12`=0,
`13`=0,`14`=0,`15`=0,`16`=0,`17`=0,`18`=0,
`19`=0,`63`=0,`64`=0,`65`=0,`66`=0,`67`=0),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="0",class="data.frame"),`1000000000011110000000000`=structure(list(
`0`=1,`1`=0,`2`=0,`3`=0,`4`=0,`5`=0,`6`=0,
`7`=0,`8`=0,`9`=0,`10`=0,`11`=1,`12`=1,
`13`=1,`14`=1,`15`=0,`16`=0,`17`=0,`18`=0,
`19`=0,`63`=0,`64`=0,`65`=0,`66`=0,`67`=0),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="2",class="data.frame"),`1010110000000001000000000`=structure(list(
`0`=1,`1`=0,`2`=1,`3`=0,`4`=1,`5`=1,`6`=0,
`7`=0,`8`=0,`9`=0,`10`=0,`11`=0,`12`=0,
`13`=0,`14`=0,`15`=1,`16`=0,`17`=0,`18`=0,
`19`=0,`63`=0,`64`=0,`65`=0,`66`=0,`67`=0),.Names=c("0",
"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12",
"13","14","15","16","17","18","19","63","64","65","66",
"67"),row.names="1",class="data.frame")),.Names=c("0000000000000000000000000",
"0000000000000000000011111","0000000100000000111100000","0000001111100000000000000",
"0111110000000000000000000","1000000000011110000000000","1010110000000001000000000"
))
```

Comment: Could you show the `dput` of x9[1:3] i.e `dput(x9[1:3])`  Are these `matrices` with `1 row`?

Comment: @akrun here's the output from dput dput(x9[[3]])
structure(list(`0` = 0, `1` = 0, `2` = 0, `3` = 0, `4` = 0, `5` = 0, 
    `6` = 0, `7` = 1, `8` = 0, `9` = 0, `10` = 0, `11` = 0, `12` = 0, 
    `13` = 0, `14` = 0, `15` = 0, `16` = 1, `17` = 1, `18` = 1, 
    `19` = 1, `63` = 0, `64` = 0, `65` = 0, `66` = 0, `67` = 0), .Names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "63", "64", "65", "66", 
"67"), row.names = "4", class = "data.frame")

Comment: I was trying to recreate the list using the example you showed. Based on that, it worked here. If it is not, please show a small example that didn't work using dput

Comment: @akrun :)  thanks bud, my my x9 list object has 7 elements, I am looking for automating this....the code below does what I want for one of the elements x9[[3]], I have do to this 7 times...is there way to automate this in a loop ?                                       x10= as.matrix(x9[[3]])
     
     toAdd = setdiff(colnames(x10), rownames(x10))
     
     m = matrix(0, ncol = ncol(x10), nrow = length(toAdd), dimnames = 
     list(toAdd,colnames(x10)))

     x11 = rbind(x10, m)

Comment: Can you tell me whether each of the list elements are different in `colnames`.  In the code below, I assumed that all the list elements have the same column names. Otherwise, we have to create the `m2` within in each `list` element and then do the indexing.

Comment: It is easier to do the `dput` of those 7 elements and paste it on your post.  The previous dput does give me error.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct `dput`.  I tried to copy/paste but get error `Error: unexpected '=' in "x9 <- structure(list(0000000000000000000000000 ="`

Comment: @akrun the column names for each list element is the same (...on the very top..i listed three elements..x9[[1]],x9[[2]], x9[[3]] they all have the same columns different rows. Also I updated the question with the dput for all the list elements dput(x9)

Comment: I am getting errors with your dput.

Comment: @akrun how about now ?

Comment: It still gives the error. `Error: unexpected '=' in "x9 <- structure(list(0000000000000000000000000="`  Check whether you are getting any error by pasting this to Rconsole `x9 <-structure...`

Comment: @Tyone Williams Is it a nested list?  Can you share the data in dropbox or something and also the code you used to create the list?

Comment: @akrun here's the website for the dput http://textuploader.com/ox9b

Comment: Thanks, it now works.  One doubt, the first list element seems to be square matrix already, but it only have 0 values.  Is it the `m2` matrix you created.   Also, from the output, it looks like all the elements have the same column name, so it should work with the code I provided.  Perhaps the `1st element` was creating trouble?

Comment: I updated the post.  Your list elements were `data.frame`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 m2 <- matrix(0, nrow=ncol(lst1[[1]]), ncol=ncol(lst1[[1]]),
         dimnames=list(colnames(lst1[[1]]), colnames(lst1[[1]])))

 res <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {m2[rownames(x),colnames(x)] <- x; m2})
```

#### Update

Using the new dataset `x9` based on the `dput` output

```
x9New <- x9[-1] #deleting the first element as it was already square and without any `1`s
 m2 <- matrix(0, nrow=ncol(x9New[[1]]), ncol=ncol(x9New[[1]]),
     dimnames=list(colnames(x9New[[1]]), colnames(x9New[[1]])))

 res1 <- lapply(x9New, function(x) {x1 <- as.matrix(x)
                    m2[rownames(x1), colnames(x1)] <- x1
                    m2})


 unname(sapply(res1,dim))
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 #[1,]   25   25   25   25   25   25
 #[2,]   25   25   25   25   25   25
```

#### data

```
 lst1 <-  list(structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(1L, 
 25L), .Dimnames = list("2", c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
 "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
 "18", "19", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67"))), structure(c(0L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(1L, 25L), .Dimnames = list(
"0", c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"63", "64", "65", "66", "67"))), structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), .Dim = c(1L, 25L), .Dimnames = list(
"5", c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"63", "64", "65", "66", "67"))))
```